# Single word for collective knowledge of plants and cultivation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to find one single word that covers knowledge concerning both the properties and cultivation of plants, but have come short with some words.

Here are some of the words I thought of, but eventually found lacking:

**Botany**: I feel this implies purely scientific research on plants, ignoring the cultivation of plants and things like crop rotations and irrigation techniques.

**Agriculture**: I think this word only covers food crops and plants commonly grown for decoration. I feel it misses out on the more thorough knowledge of all (not just commonly cultivated) plants, including currently unknown ones.

Ultimately, I'm looking for a word that encompasses the subjects of both Botany and Agriculture, but have come short for now.

Comment: Would *horticulture* fit your needs?   - The science or art of cultivating fruits, vegetables, flowers, or ornamental plants.

Comment: Well, unless you're a muggle, there's "herbology."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking into this, I just learned a new word:

[Agronomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agronomy)

> Agronomy is the science and technology of producing and using plants for food, fuel, fibre, and land reclamation. Agronomy
>   encompasses work in the areas of plant genetics, plant physiology,
>   meteorology, and soil science. Agronomy is the application of a
>   combination of sciences like biology, chemistry, economics, ecology,
>   earth science, and genetics. Agronomists today are involved with many
>   issues including producing food, creating healthier food, managing
>   environmental impact of agriculture, and extracting energy from
>   plants. Agronomists often specialize in areas such as **crop
>   rotation**, irrigation and drainage, plant breeding, **plant
>   physiology**, soil classification, soil fertility, weed control, and
>   insect and pest control.

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 17):

[Horticulture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horticulture)

> Horticulture is the branch of agriculture that deals with the art, science, technology, and business of plant cultivation. It includes the cultivation of fruits, vegetables, nuts, seeds, herbs, sprouts, mushrooms, algae, flowers, seaweeds and non-food crops such as grass and ornamental trees and plants. It also includes plant conservation, landscape restoration, landscape and garden design, construction, and maintenance, and arboriculture.

Horticulturists apply their knowledge, skills, and technologies used to grow intensively produced plants for human food and non-food uses and for personal or social needs. Their work involves plant propagation and cultivation with the aim of improving plant growth, yields, quality, nutritional value, and resistance to insects, diseases, and environmental stresses. They work as gardeners, growers, therapists, designers, and technical advisors in the food and non-food sectors of horticulture.

Comment: I've seen Horticulture pass by during my search, but I feel it generally hovered towards the same problems Agriculture has. On the other hand, giving the Wikipedia page a read (more specifically the Scope chapter) has given me a slightly different opinion. Regardless, I'll keep the question open for about another day to see if there are any other words people can find.

Comment: +1. I believe horticulture is the word that you want. I don't find it directed towards food.

Comment: I accepted Agronomy because it fit most into the context I was going to use it in. Regardless of context, many others will find this answer more useful instead. +1

Answer (score 2):

Granted, it's not a single word, but ***plant sciences*** would seem to encompass both areas. That's a department name in US universities, for example.

Comment: _Domestic science_ certainly qualifies as a single lexeme.

Answer (score 1):

The term that you are looking for is ***agricultural botany***. It is the discipline that combines *botany* and *agriculture*. It is not a single word but it is sometimes shortened as ***[agri-botany](http://www.narc.org.np/narc/wheat_variety_released.php)***.

> The final "new" branch of Botany is which we must briefly mention, at least so that its historical links can be seen, is **agricultural botany**. Here, after nearly 200 years, we find the University accepting and catering for a scientific approach to crop cultivation for which the first professor of Botany, Richard Bradley, had hoped in vain.
>
> <sub>*The Shaping of Cambridge Botany* By Stuart Max Walters, John Stevens Henslow</sub>

There is even a *[National Institute of Agricultural Botany](http://www.niab.com/)* in Cambridge, UK. There is also an *agricultural botany* department in several universities including *[University of Reading](http://r4d.dfid.gov.uk/Search/ResearchContactsResults.aspx?SearchType=All&OrgID=884&OrganisationName=Department%20of%20Agricultural%20Botany%2C%20University%20of%20Reading)*, *[University of Zagreb](http://cirtt.unizg.hr/research-group/10/)* and *[Czech University of Life Sciences](http://www.af.czu.cz/en/?r=1238&i=1879)*.

*Horticulture* covers some scientific approaches to plant cultivation but it doesn't cover all the scientific studies of botany. In other words, it doesn't cover botany; hence there is a field called *[horticultural botany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horticultural_botany)*. It is  defined in *Wikipedia* as the study of the botany of current and potential cultivated plants, with emphasis on the ornamental plants of horticulture, by a horticultural botanist or *plantsman—plantsperson*.